# awk FNR==NR, ORS, OFS confused

Tags: awk

Please help me to understand the logic behind the function. I am little bit confused to understand it.

myscript:

```
generate_exception(){
    awk -F "," 'FNR==NR{a[ins,INS]=ins "," INS;next}{ if (!a[ins,INS]) print $0,"is not available"}' OFS="," my_$1_lookup.csv final.csv >> exception.csv
}

generate_exception ins INS
```

### my_ins_lookup.csv

```
STANDARD & POORS,XS00001,ISS ILN,SG CORP
STANDARD & POORS,XS00002,ISS ILN,SG CORP
STANDARD & POORS,XS00003,PM,US CORP
STANDARD & POORS,XS00004,LMT,US CORP
STANDARD & POORS,XS00005,NAT,FR CORP
```

### final.csv

```
MOODYS,USEQ27,N.A.
STANDARD & POORS,XS00001,N.A.
MOODYS,SGD,NR
STANDARD & POORS,XS00004,N.A.
```

### Here is my understanding:

FS: FIELD SEPARATOR (DEFAULT SPACE)

NF: NUMBER OF FIELDS IN THE CURRENT RECORD

NR: NUMBER OF CURRENT RECORDS

NR: It represents the number of the current record. For instance, the following example prints the record if the current record contains less than three fields.

FNR: It is similar to NR, but relative to the current file. It is useful when 
AWK is operating on multiple files. Value of FNR resets with new file.

ORS: It represents the output record separator and its default value is newline.

OFS: It represents the output field separator and its default value is space.

Comment: You want to know how the code works/not works/?

Comment: First, I would like to understand the logic behind the code. Second, is it working or not working.

Comment: It's very understandable that you would be confused because there's a lot about the script that makes little sense. We can probably guess what's being attempted, but I suggest you complete your question with your expected output and let us help you rewrite the function from scratch. And don't worry, we'll explain every part of the solution.

Comment: As it stands, the script shown will never produce the output shown.  Main reason is explained by karakfa below.  I think you have missed some information.  Please show correct script so we may assist.  Also, your understanding of NR and FNR is wrong, but that can be dealt with once the correct script is shown.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with this

```
awk -F "," 'FNR==NR{a[ins,INS]=ins "," INS; next}...
```

during the first file processing (current file record number equals to global record number) fill up a two dimension array with values.  However, neither `ins`, nor `INS` is defined anywhere else, so not much can be accomplished here...

My guess is you have to replace `ins` with `$1` and `INS` with `$2` based on your input files.

A re-write can be

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR        {a[$1,$2]; next} 
        !(($1,$2) in a) {print $0, "is not available"}' file1 file2
```

Comment: It adds commas together, as many as there are lines. The variable name is decidedly oddball (why an array when there is only one value? etc) but it does *something.*

Comment: I said _accomplished_, if you follow the script, it does a look up, obviously appending commas are not the intended action.